# When i change 'com.android.support:design' version from 27.1.0 to 27.1.1, Android Studio shows error

Tags: android, android-studio

I change 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0' to 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' in 'build.gradle', Android studio shows error. The message is :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion)."

But I cont find '27.1.0' in anywhere while using 'find in project'.
[image]

So how can I fix this problem without using `//noinspection GradleCompatible`.

My gradle code

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
compile 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.2.0'
compile 'dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.8'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
compile 'com.github.CymChad:BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper:2.9.30'
compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.57'
compile 'com.lzy.widget:view-core:0.1.9'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
compile 'com.umeng.sdk:share-core:6.9.0'
compile 'com.umeng.sdk:share-qq:6.9.0'
compile 'com.umeng.sdk:share-wechat:6.9.0'
compile 'com.umeng.sdk:share-sina:6.9.0'
implementation files('libs/umeng-common-1.5.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/alipaySdk-20180403.jar')
implementation files('libs/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: can you add your build.gradle to your question?

Comment: Some other library you use can have it as a dependency. Try `gradlew dependencies` on the command line to find out where it comes from.

Comment: post your gradle code

Comment: I use `gradle -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile` and find the problem...   `+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0 -> 27.1.1
`